# Is it permissible to play with cards?

Tags: sources-mekorot, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, games-toys

Someone told me the other day, that playing cards (with ace, jack king and queen...) contain Tumah and therefor should not be played with.

Did anyone hear of this? If yes, do you have a source?

Comment: Hi EHS.  For the future, to make a new line in these posts you need to do a double return.  Hope to see you around.

Comment: What's wrong with playing with something that's Tamei?

Comment: I have a feeling that the ritual-purity tag doesn't really belong here...

Comment: @Matt We don't have a kochos-hatumah tag, so this was the best I could do. (If someone thinks there is a need for such a tag...)

Comment: See Aruch Hashulchan 670:9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[R' Tzvi Elimelech from Dinov](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_32292_88.pdf) (as well as the Chayey Adam) said that קרטן (cards) has  the same Gematria as Satan and was the Klippa which the Greeks wanted  to introduce to the Jews.

[Someone](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_41472_79.pdf) also pointed out that there are 36 cards which are the opposite side to the 36 Masechtos.

Comment: ....."Someone"?

Comment: PTIJ? [15 char]

Comment: Playing cards are a Chinese invention, not a Greek one. They didn't make it to Europe until the 1300s

Comment: Does this explain why milk in Israel is sold in bags instead of _cartons_?

Comment: There are 37 Masechtot with Bavli and 39 with Yerushalmi, not 36. And aren't there 52 cards?

Comment: And here's the relevant Kedushas Levi he mentions: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50006&st=&pgnum=51

Comment: It just goes to show that you can "prove" almost anything and its opposite if you really want to. And perhaps there are more elevated uses for "klaf" than "klafim". It looks as though it was a justification for discouraging a practice that it was felt was "not appropriate" for a shomer mitzvot.

Comment: 36 cards? Huh? Then what was I doing all those years when I played 52 card pickup?